# React Number Format unit test with isAllowed

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using the react number format for inputting the number input fields.

```
         <TargetRow>
                   <NumberFormat
                        type="text"
                        isNumericString={true}
                        decimalScale={2}
                        name="otbTarget"
                        value={otbTarget === null ? '' : otbTarget}
                        className="TargetRow__input TargetRow__otbTarget"
                        onBlur={this.updateTarget}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeOTBTarget}
                        isAllowed={this.limitInputValue}
                    />

         />
```

function for the **isAllowed**, is to limit the length of values entered in the field.

```
limitInputValue = ({ value }: NumberFormatValues ) =>  value.length <= ALLOWED_INPUT_LENGTH;
```

I need to write a unit test for this functionality, to check if the values entered in the field with **NumberFormat** gets restricted by using the isAllowed method.

I tried using the enzyme simulate for change, but as it turns out it calls the `handleChangeOTBTarget` method, which is as expected.

I am not able to understand how the `isAllowed` will be triggered.

Unit test which I am writing is :

```
it('should restrict values with ALLOWED_INPUT_LENGTH', async () => {
    // ALLOWED_INPUT_LENGTH = 3
    const mockTarget = 1234512345;
    component = shallow(<TargetRow {...defaultProps} otbTarget={mockTarget} />); 

    const targetInput = component.find('.TargetRow__otbTarget');
    targetInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: mockTarget } });
    targetInput.simulate('blur');
    expect(targetInput.props().value).toBe( 123 );
});
```

As you can see there is way to simulate onchange, which is working as stated above. But I am not able to trigger the method which is on `isAllowed`

Comment: I am kind of jumping off-topic here, but why not look at whether NumberFormat value length will be more than `ALLOWED_INPUT_LENGTH`? Or is it required that you know `isAllowed()` function is being called? I think it would be great if you could provide unit test example and exact `NumberFormat` component package for easier debugging

Comment: Added my unit test. I am able to trigger the onchange but I need to find a way to trigger the isAllowed, and call that method so that I can make sure that whenever the input changes and/or added the value is restricted with the isAllowed method.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something as the following:

```
it('should restrict values with ALLOWED_INPUT_LENGTH', async () => {
    const isValid
    // ALLOWED_INPUT_LENGTH = 3
    const mockTarget = 1234512345;
    component = shallow(<TargetRow {...defaultProps} otbTarget={mockTarget} />);
    component.instance().limitInputValue = jest.fn();  // MOCK THE METHOD WE ADD TO isAllowed prop
 


    const targetInput = component.find('.TargetRow__otbTarget');
    targetInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: mockTarget } });
    targetInput.simulate('blur');
    expect(targetInput.props().value).toBe( 123 );
    expect(component.instance().limitInputValue).toHaveBeenCalled() // Check if the method has been called at all
});
```

Comment: This does not work. I checked by console.log statement, how the "isAllowed" behave when the key is pressed to change input. I see first the "isAllowed" is called and then the change method. I am not sure whether the onChange event triggers the "isAllowed" or keypress. I tried simulating keypress as well but it does not work.